# Trouble with If/Else Statements to move through 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, combinatorics, knights-tour

Working on a version of the knight's tour. The program is not acting the way I think it would given my code. I am getting several different strange discrepencies. The 'knight' is going out of bounds though I set up paramters for it not to. There are also more movements being made than there should be given my while loop. Mess with the i value, j value, and the number in the while loop and you will get several strange results. I have the value set to 32 for now just to see what will happen. Here is the code and the result:

```
#include <iostream>
int board[8][8];
void printBoard();
bool openSpace(int i,int j);
int startingPoint=0, m , n, i , j;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        i=4;
        j=2;
        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
        std::fill_n(&board[0][0], sizeof(board) / sizeof(**board), -1);//set all points to -1
        //Set the starting point to zero
        board[i][j] = startingPoint;//plot the starting point
        while(startingPoint<32)//for the first 32 points
        {
            if (i-2>0)
            {
                if(j+1<8)
                {
                    m=i-2;
                    n=j-2;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i-2;
                        j=j+1;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
                    }
                }
                if(j-1>0)
                    m=i-2;
                    n=j-1;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i-2;
                        j=j-1;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
                    }
            }
            if (i-1>0)
            {
                if(j+2<8)
                {
                    m=i-1;
                    n=j+2;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i-1;
                        j=j+2;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;

                    }
                }
                if(j-2>0)
                    m=i-1;
                    n=j-2;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i-1;
                        j=j-2;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;

                    }
            }
            if (i+1<8)
            {
                if(j+2<8)
                {
                    m=i+1;
                    n=j+2;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i+1;
                        j=j+2;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
                    }
                }
                if(j-2>0)
                    m=i+1;
                    n=j-2;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i+1;
                        j=j-2;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;

                    }
            }
            if (i+2<8){
                if(j+1<8)
                {
                    m=i+2;
                    n=j+1;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i+2;
                        j=j+1;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
                    }
                }
                if(j-1>0)
                    m=i+2;
                    n=j-1;
                    if (openSpace(m,n))
                    {
                        startingPoint++;
                        i=i+2;
                        j=j-1;
                        board[i][j]=startingPoint;
                        cout<<"Move: "<<startingPoint<<" Coordinates: "<<i<<","<<j<<endl;
                    }
            }else{
            cout<<"I don't understand"<<endl;
            }
        }//end while
        printBoard();
}

void printBoard()
{
    //We need to loop through each row one by one
    for (int row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
    //now loop through each column in the row
        for(int column=0; column<8; column++)
        {
            cout<<board[row][column]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

//Check for open surrounding spaces
bool openSpace(int m,int n){
    if (board[m][n] == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Result:

```
Move: 0 Coordinates: 4,2
Move: 1 Coordinates: 2,3
Move: 2 Coordinates: 0,2
Move: 3 Coordinates: 1,4
Move: 4 Coordinates: 2,2
Move: 5 Coordinates: 4,3
Move: 6 Coordinates: 6,2
Move: 7 Coordinates: 4,3
Move: 8 Coordinates: 3,5
Move: 9 Coordinates: 4,7
Move: 10 Coordinates: 5,5
Move: 11 Coordinates: 7,6
Move: 12 Coordinates: 5,7
Move: 13 Coordinates: 3,6
Move: 14 Coordinates: 2,4
Move: 15 Coordinates: 3,2
Move: 16 Coordinates: 5,3
Move: 17 Coordinates: 7,2
Move: 18 Coordinates: 5,3
Move: 19 Coordinates: 4,5
Move: 20 Coordinates: 3,3
Move: 21 Coordinates: 4,1
Move: 22 Coordinates: 6,0
Move: 23 Coordinates: 4,-1
Move: 24 Coordinates: 3,1
Move: 25 Coordinates: 2,-1
Move: 26 Coordinates: 3,-3
Move: 27 Coordinates: 5,-2
Move: 28 Coordinates: 4,0
Move: 29 Coordinates: 5,2
Move: 30 Coordinates: 6,0
I don't understand
Move: 31 Coordinates: 7,-2
I don't understand
Move: 32 Coordinates: 5,-1
Move: 33 Coordinates: 6,1
I don't understand
-1 -1 2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 3 -1 -1 25
-1 -1 4 1 14 26 -1 -1
-1 24 15 20 -1 8 13 23
28 21 0 7 -1 19 27 32
-1 -1 29 18 -1 10 -1 12
30 33 6 -1 -1 -1 31 -1
-1 -1 17 -1 -1 -1 11 -1


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.172 s
Press any key to continue.
```

So yeah, why are there 34 moves, why are the going off the board?

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger and how to use it to step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I second that you need to learn some debugging skills. You can either use a visual debugger or add more cout statements to print the values of variables.

Comment: You might want to `n=j+1;` instead of `n=j-2;` at the very beginning of the loop.

Comment: The `else` you are getting corresponds to `if ((i+2) < 8)`, which is not true as `i` is 6. Should the `else` be for the inner `if`? You are at least missing opening `{` after the inner `if`.

Comment: Check your brackets! They are wrong on several places.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are few problems.

First you check the allowed moves one after other

```
while (starting point<32){
  if (not over right board){
  }
  if (not over left board){
  }
  ....
}
```

This means that multiple `if` statements can be true until the `while` loop is checked, hence you go over the limit of 32. You could use `continue` statement after each move which goes to the beginning of the loop and  does the check or you have to do the comparison after every move and then `break` from the loop.

Then you are missing brackets `{` in several places.

Then as pointed out by felix in the first if you should have `n=j+1` not `n=j-2`.

You might want to consider slight rewriting of the code to be easier to read. E.g., you could make a function which tries to make the move and return true it is successful.

```
bool tryToMove(int stepI, int stepJ){
  int n = i+stepI;
  int m = j+stepJ;
  if (n>=0 && n<8 && m>=0 && m<8 && openSpace(n,m)){
    i = n;
    j = m;
    board[i][j] = startingPoint;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and you can use it like

```
if (tryToMove(-2,1)){
  if (startingPoint == 32) break;
}
if (tryToMove(-2,-1)){
  if (startingPoint == 32) break;
}
...
```

or instead use `continue`, but that changes the order of move.

There will be few more comparisons than in your code, but it is much easier to see what is going on.